# Trouble shoot maven installation on mac

Tags: maven

This is my bash_profile file

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Desktop/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
```

The unzipped maven download is present in $HOME/Desktop/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin. But

```
mvn -v
```

does not work. Anything I am missing?

Comment: run command "which mvn" to see if it is able to find mvn executable from terminal

Comment: "mvn not found" is what I am getting

Comment: that's the problem.  Your path is not set properly.  echo $PATH & see if mvn directory is there

Comment: Thanks @Satish, the path is not set correctly. Can you please tell me how I can set it?

Comment: Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYVEZTmBiuc&feature=youtu.be.  Plenty of material how to set PATH variable in net

Comment: Is the unzipped download in ` $HOME/Desktop/apache-maven-3.6.3` instead of ` $HOME/Desktop/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin` ?

Comment: yes it is the unzipped download in that location